# What is $10$ in base $11$ and what is $11$ in base $11$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

I am not understanding how to write numbers in bases. For example, $10=10\times11^0$ so it should be $10$ in base $11$. But also $11=0\times11^0+1\times11^1$ so $11$ is $10$ in base $11$. So both $10$ and $11$ are $10$ in base $11$?

Comment: people generally start using letters for 2 digit numbers. So 10 in base 10 converted to base 11 is A and 11 in base 10 converted to base 11 is 11

Comment: As an example, counting is like $1,2,\cdots,8,9,A,10,11,\cdots,18,19,1A,20,\cdots,A8,A9,AA,100$ in base $11$.

Comment: For bases larger than ten you have to introduce new digits.  Commonly we start using letters.  So 10 would be the digit "A".  11 is 11^1 so it would be written 10.  In fact in base x, x is always written as 10.  2 in base 2 is 10, 3 in base 3 ois 10, etc.

Comment: It *is* the number we think of as 10 but we need a new 11th symbol to express it.  Bas 2 has 2 digits, base 8 has 8, and base 10 has 10.  So base 11 is going ing to need 11 digits.  So we have to make up a digit to represent 9 +1.

Comment: 11 is not a very common base, but 16 is. Try googling the word "hexadecimal" for a similar number system.

Answer (score 5):

In base 10, we have 10 symbols for digits. In base 2, we have 2. Likewise, in base 11, we must have 11 - but 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 only makes ten. So we have to introduce a new symbol (we generally use A) to be that eleventh digit. "A" represents a value of 10 in a single digit.

So in base 11, 10 will be denoted A (because it is A 1's and zero 11's). 11 will be denoted 10 (because it is one 11 and zero 1's). Similarly, 21 would be 1A (one 11 and A 1's).

Comment: Where can I learn more in a systematic way about decimal expansions so that I deal with them with ease?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know a good standard resource - I don't recall where I learned this, for example. But a quick Google turned up http://www.purplemath.com/modules/numbbase.htm , which looks like a reasonably good presentation.

Comment: It would be better to subscript numbers to show what base they are in.  So in base $11$, $10_{10}$ will be denoted $A_{11}$, $11_{10}$ will be denoted $10_{11}$

Answer (score 0):

For an integer base $b \ge 2$ and nonnegative integer $n$, we can express $n$ in base $b$ using the notation $$n = (d_m, d_{m-1}, \ldots, d_1, d_0)_b = \sum_{k=0}^m d_k b^k,$$ where $$d_k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, b-1\}$$ for all $k$; moreover, such a representation is **unique**.  That is to say, writing $n$ in base $b$ amounts to finding a sequence $\{d_k\}_{k \ge 0}$ of nonnegative integers **strictly less than** $b$ for which the above sum equals $n$.

For example, let us choose $n = 32597$, $b = 23$.  Then the largest power of $23$ that is less than or equal to $n$ is $23^3 = 12167$, and the the quotient of $n$ divided by $23^3$ is $2$.  This tells us $d_3 = 2$, so $$n = 2 \cdot 23^3 + d_2 \cdot 23^2 + d_1 \cdot 23^1 + d_0 \cdot 23^0.$$  To solve for the subsequent terms, we simply subtract and proceed with the remainder:  $$n - 2 \cdot 23^3 = 8263,$$ and the largest power of $23$ that is less than $8263$ is $23^2 = 529$, and $\lfloor 8263 / 529 \rfloor = 15$, so $d_2 = 15$.  Repeating the process until the end, we obtain $$32597 = 2 \cdot 23^3 + 15 \cdot 23^2 + 14 \cdot 23^1 + 6 \cdot 23^0,$$ and we can write this more compactly as $$n = (2, 15, 14, 6)_{23}.$$

This was a fairly detailed example.  At this point, it's worth noting that, for convenience, we can think of such representations as comprising an **infinite** sequence of digits $d_k$, and that if $n$ is finite, then there exists some $m$ for which $d_k = 0$ for all $k > m$; so for example, $$(2,15,14,6)_{23} = (\ldots, 0, 2, 15, 14, 6)_{23}$$ or if we wrote the digits in "reverse"--that is, in order of increasing significance--we might say $$\{d_k\}_{k\ge 0} = (6, 14, 15, 2, 0, 0, 0, \ldots).$$  This affords us the convenience of not having to specify $m$, and that in some sense, the base-$b$ representation of any nonnegative integer is an infinite sequence of nonnegative integers less than $b$.

That said, how would we answer the original question?  Well, in base $b = 11$, the number $n = 10$ is less than $b$, so we simply write $$10 = (10)_{23} = 10 \cdot 11^0.$$  Thus, the sequence corresponding to such $n$ and $b$ is $$\{d_k\}_{k\ge 0} = (10,0,0,0,\ldots).$$  Note we do not need to resort to using letters or other symbols.

What is $11$ in base $11$?  Well, this should be clear now:  $$11 = 1 \cdot 11^1 + 0 \cdot 11^0 = (1,0)_{11} = (0,1,0,0,0,\ldots).$$

Let's try some more.  What is $n = 57$ in base $b = 3$?  We have $$57 = 2 \cdot 3^3 + 0 \cdot 3^2 + 1 \cdot 3^1 + 0 \cdot 3^0 = (2,0,1,0)_3 = (0,1,0,2,0,0,0,\ldots).$$  How about $300$ in base $100$?  This is just $$300 = 3 \cdot 100^1 + 0 \cdot 100^0 = (3,0)_{100} = (0,3,0,0,0,\ldots).$$  By now, you should find the process familiar.  Try more examples; just pick an integer $b \ge 2$ and any nonnegative $n$, and work it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that $11 = 10\times 1 + 1$ and $10 = 10\times 1 + 0$ without knowing what the base is. The base could be 9 + 4. The question is, what is $10 - 1$?

Comment: While the OP reflects some confusion about radix representation and arithmetic, I have difficulty seeing how say the wrong question has been asked amounts to any kind of answer to it.